# What is the difference between "find -H" and "find -L" command?

Tags: find, symlink, hard-link

When I executed the command both commands gave the same output. I created a soft link and a hard link for a file but still both commands gave the same output. Is there a difference between `find -H` and `find -L`?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us a minimal working example that demonstrates the problem. (It should be possible to run from an empty directory and illustrate what you are finding confusing.) Also, what research have you done in order to answer this yourself? At least on my system, the man page for `find` describes `-P`, `-L` and `-H` very nearly *at the top*. Your question is receiving downvotes because it doesn't contain the information necessary to provide a good answer nor any evidence of effort in trying to find the answer yourself before asking others.

Comment: I believe that this question should never have been closed, and (at the risk of ruffling some feathers) that the people who voted to close it might not have fully [grokked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grok) it. (1) @aCVn says “Please edit your question to show us a minimal working example that demonstrates the problem.” The next clause, “It should be possible to run from an empty directory …”, is the height of either irony or sarcastic snarkiness. The question literally, explicitly asks «What is the difference between “find -H” and “find -L” …?» … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) … In other words, «I do “find -H” and “find -L” and I get identical results. When do they ever do anything different?» ***Trivially**,* “find -H” and “find -L” will produce identical results in an empty directory, as will (for example) `ls`, `ls -A`, `ls -b`, `ls -c`, `ls -C`, `ls -F`, `ls -G`, `ls -i`, `ls -m`, `ls -q`, `ls -r`, `ls -t` and about a dozen others — including (spoiler alert) `ls -H` and `ls -L`. The trick — the challenge — what the question asks — is how to create a minimal working example that demonstrates that the options *do,* in fact, do different things. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (2) aCVn doesn’t exactly say “RTFM”, but they come close.  Well, imagine that you’re just learning Unix / Linux.  You have a basic knowledge of some basic commands (e.g., `cat` / `more` / `less`, an editor, `cp`, `ln`, `mv`, `rm`, `mkdir`, `rmdir`, maybe ``chmod``, etc.) and somebody tells you that `ls` is the command to list files and directories, and that almost every letter in the alphabet is a valid option to `ls` — but they don’t tell you any details, and you don’t have access to any relevant documentation. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  So you try to discover what they all mean by experimenting. If you create `file1`, and then `file2`, and then `file3`, you’re going to have a hard time discovering that `-r` and `-t` do different things. If you don’t know what **`.`** and **`..`** are, you’re in for a surprise. If you don’t know the lore of “dot-files”, it’s going to take you while to figure out `-A`. … … … … How long is it going to take you to figure out `-H` and `-L`? How long is it going to take you to think of creating symbolic links and seeing how `ls` treats them when you specify different options? … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  The OP says “I created a soft link and a hard link for a file but still both commands gave the same output.”  That’s the ***one thing*** that they mention in the question that they tried.  Do you really believe that they jumped directly to that experiment *without reading the man page?*  Obviously they read the man page.  As I said in my answer, man pages are hard to understand.  I know ``find`` like the back of my hand — I’ve been using it since before symbolic links even existed — and even I had to read the man page multiple times before I was able to write my answer.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  **TL;DR** — The question is perfectly clear.  The OP read the man page, and it was not helpful (enough).  Googling the title of the question doesn’t yield anything that addresses the question other than the man page.  The question should be reopened.  (And maybe upvoted, for being a concise, seemingly simple inquiry that elicited a non-simple, non-trivial, non-obvious answer that isn’t wallpapered all over the Internet, and because it has been unfairly downvoted.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`find` is not going to treat hard links specially
except insofar as the `-links` test is concerned. 
Symbolic links *to files* are going to be treated very similarly, too.

I would read the `find` man page to you,
but I assume that you've already read it. 
Man pages are written in a cryptic language
that is hard for beginners to understand. 
An example would probably help.  Do this:

```
$ mkdir dir1 dir2 dir3

$ touch dir1/file1 dir2/file2 dir3/file3

$ ln -s dir2 two

$ cd dir1

$ ln -s ../dir3 three

$ cd ..

$ ls -lR                                # I have deleted my user name from the below.
.:
total 1
drwxr-xr-x 1           0 Sep  4 13:08 dir1
drwxr-xr-x 1           0 Sep  4 13:08 dir2
drwxr-xr-x 1           0 Sep  4 13:08 dir3
lrwxrwxrwx 1           4 Sep  4 13:08 two -> dir2

./dir1:
total 1
-rw-r--r-- 1           0 Sep  4 13:08 file1
lrwxrwxrwx 1           7 Sep  4 13:08 three -> ../dir3

./dir2:
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1           0 Sep  4 13:08 file2

./dir3:
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1           0 Sep  4 13:08 file3

$ find dir1 two
dir1
dir1/file1
dir1/three
two

$ find -P dir1 two                      # This is the default; i.e., same as the above.
dir1
dir1/file1
dir1/three
two

$ find -H dir1 two
dir1
dir1/file1
dir1/three
two
two/file2

$ find -L dir1 two
dir1
dir1/file1
dir1/three
dir1/three/file3
two
two/file2
```

Note that:

- In the default behavior (i.e., the `-P` behavior),
  `find` does not follow either symbolic link. 
  `two` (in the top-level directory) and `dir1/three`
  are simply reported as objects.
- Under `-H`, the symbolic link `two` → `dir2` is followed
  (i.e., we get to see `file2`, which is in `dir2`)
  because `two` is specified *on the* `find` *command line*. 
  Note that `dir1/three` is still reported as an object.
- Under `-L`, both symbolic links are followed. 
  We get to see `file2`, because the `two` → `dir2` link is followed,
  and we get to see `file3`,
  because the `dir1/three` → `../dir3` link is followed.

If it's not perfectly clear to you now,
try running the `find` commands in my example with `-ls` at the end
(as an alternative to the default `-print`)
and pay particular attention to the ways `two` and `three` are listed. 
You will notice that symbolic links *to files*
are also reported differently under the different options.

Here's another example:

```
$ ln -s /bin/sh mysh

$ find . -size +9

$ find -H . -size +9

$ find -L . -size +9
./mysh
```

The symbolic link `./mysh` is small. 
It points to `/bin/sh`, which is a fairly large file. 
Testing with `-size`,
`./mysh` is treated as being small under `-P` (default) and `-H`,
but it is treated as being large under `-L`,
because `-L` means "look at the file that the link points to".

---

Yet another example:

- `find . -type f` (and `find -H . -type f`) will find plain files only.
- `find . "(" -type f -o -type l ")"` will find plain files
  and (all) symbolic links.
- `find -L . -type f` will find plain files
  and symbolic links *that point to plain files*. 
  (Also, if the directory tree contains any symbolic links to directories,
  *those* directories will also be searched.)