# What is the difference between -H and -L options of chown?

Tags: symlink, recursive, chown

From the `chown` manpage:

```
The following options modify how a hierarchy is traversed when the -R option is also specified.  If more than one is specified, only the final one takes effect.

-H     if a command line argument is a symbolic link to a directory, traverse it

-L     traverse every symbolic link to a directory encountered

-P     do not traverse any symbolic links (default)
```

What is the exact difference between the `-H` and `-L` options? As I understood it, `-H` allows for directory symlink  traversal only when that directory is specified as argument, where `-L` traverses all directory symlinks  in any case. 
(These options apply only when `chown`ing recursively using the `-R` option. In non-recursive mode, a directory symlink specified as argument is always traversed.)  Is this correct?

Comment: That how I understand it too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your understanding is correct; these options match the same [options in `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/307900/86440).

Thus

```
chown -R .
```

or

```
chown -R -P .
```

changes the owner recursively without de-referencing any symlinks;

```
chown -R -H *
```

changes the owner recursively, de-referencing any symlinks in the current directory (since they end up being part of the arguments) but

```
chown -R -H .
```

still doesn't de-reference any symlink, and finally

```
chown -R -L .
chown -R -L *
```

both de-reference syminks.

(As an aside for the examples above, note that `.` and `*` don't necessarily result in the same outcome, depending on your shell's globbing options — `*` typically doesn't match dotfiles.)